# How to transfer sensor data and audio data saved in internal memory of Moto 360 to an Android phone?

Tags: android, wear-os, data-transfer, moto-360

I'm recently developing apps on android wearable(MOTO 360). I am recording audio and sensor data on to the internal memory of the wearable. How can I access the data that is saved? The watch will not be paired with the phone during data collection. So how can I access these files and copy it to the phone at a later point of time?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Data Layer API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html).